# Redirect not working as expected

Tags: javascript, redirect, seo

It should work as follows: If url matches domain then redirect to new domain + add url path + query string:

```
if (window.location.href == "www.heelsteal.com.au") {
    var pathName = window.location.pathname 
   window.location = ("www.wittner.com.au/" + pathName + "?string=redirect"); 
}
```

All I get is `undefined`.

Comment: Example: http://www.heelsteal.com.au/passo-white.html should redirect to http://www.wittner.com.au/passo-white.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `indexOf()`.

`indexOf()` will return `-1` if the string is not found or return `0` if the string is found.

`window.location.origin` will return the domain name so we can use this in the `if` condition.

`window.location.pathname` as you already know will return the path but if no path exists it will return `/` so I have removed this from the redirection URL otherwise you will get **www.wittner.com.au//somepath?string=redirect** rather than **www.wittner.com.au/somepath?string=redirect**

```
if(window.location.origin.indexOf('heelsteal.com.au')>-1){
window.location.href='http://www.wittner.com.au'+window.location.pathname+'?string=redirect';
}
```

If you have any questions about the above source code please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps, happy coding!